# Parsing Delimited Data and Matching Single Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently I have column (Details) which is a delimited string. I require the ability to parse and match Batch ID value against CX.STRING_4 (batch ID) value from another table.

SQL 2008r2

```
Details Column String: ex
Request to prepare method. Context: Site: | Factory: | Unite ID: | Batch ID:0000123456 | Product Name: |
```

Any thoughts on an approach? e.g Inner Join/Parse function

Comment: so you just want to extract the batch ID? will there only be one batchID in the string?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract the value but also match against it, pulling data based on matching. There is only a single batch at a time within the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you would extract that would be using `substring` with `charindex` and some other manipulators.

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'Request to prepare method. Context: Site: | Factory: | Unite ID: | Batch ID:0000123456 | Product Name: |'

select substring(@str,charindex('Batch ID',@str),charindex('|',substring(@str,charindex('Batch ID:',@str),99)) - 1)
```

You can match against it in a few ways using this same syntax.

Comment: no problem @Diego83. Don't forget to take a moment and [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no space after "Batch ID:", and a space after the actual value of the Batch ID, you can do something like:

```
declare @str varchar(255) = 'Request to prepare method. Context: Site: | Factory: | Unite ID: | Batch ID:0000123456 | Product Name: |'

select @str
     -- Start of "Batch ID:" string
    ,charindex('Batch ID:', @str)
     -- Start of the actual Batch ID
    ,charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9 
     -- position of the space following the Batch ID
    ,charindex(' ', @str, charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9)
     -- length of the Batch ID
    ,charindex(' ', @str, charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9) - (charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9)
     -- pull it all together to extract the actual Batch ID
    ,substring(@str, charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9, charindex(' ', @str, charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9) - (charindex('Batch ID:', @str) + 9))
```

Comment: My thought is first to extract and then compare and lastly present based on matching against another table.

Comment: Batch ID String is located within the PVXMIHS Table under DETAILS Column. And PVXME has the CX_STRING_4 which is also a batch which I'm attempt to match against.

Comment: SELECT
PVXME.CX_STRING_5,
PVXME.CX_STRING_4,
PVXMIHS.USER_NAME,
PVXME.ME,
PVXME.MT,
PVXME.MT_VERSION,
PVXME.CX_STRING_6,
PVXME.CX_STRING_9
FROM
PVXME RIGHT OUTER JOIN PVXMI ON (PVXMI.MI=PVXME.MI)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PVXMIHS ON (PVXMI.MI=PVXMIHS.MI)
WHERE
(
PVXME.CX_STRING_4 = CX_STRING_4
AND
PVXMIHS.WHAT = 'MethodPrepare'
AND
PVXME.MT = ME_METHOD
)

Comment: Any thoughts combing a substring within a join statement. This results in a blank return.
SELECT
PVXME.CX_STRING_5,PVXME.CX_STRING_4,PVXMIHS.USER_NAME,PVXME.ME,PVXME.MT,PVXME.MT_VERSION,PVXME.CX_STRING_6,PVXME.CX_STRING_9,PVXME.START_DATE_LOCAL,*
FROM PVXME
Full JOIN PVXMIHS ON (SUBSTRING('Request to prepare method.  Context:  Site: | Factory: | Unit ID: | Batch ID: | Product Name: | Material Name: | Operation or Phase: | Lot ID: | Analyzer ID: | Sample ID: | Sample Point: | Method Activity: | Batch Activity: | Sample Date/Time:|',79,10))=PVXME.CX_STRING_4